# Microsoft Linq Expression Tree Serialization Format implementation?

Tags: sql-server, serialization, expression-trees

Included in the spec for SQL Server is a format called [LINQ Expression Tree Serialization Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131805%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I would expect to find an implementation of the spec somewhere in SQL Server.

Is there such an implementation? How would I reference it from my project? Any chance that it's .NET Standard compliant?

Comment: Finally found something (but it's not very encouraging): MS StreamInsight has an implementation of serialization to this protocol, but all the relevant classes are defined as `internal`.